# Applying a column based condition in an interactive report on first page load in Oracle APEX

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle-apex, interactive-grid

I have a requirement in Oracle Apex's Interactive report. At first load, only that data should appear whose Operation is not deleted. This should also reflect in the export of the report.
However, they want to provide an option that is user should be able to see the deleted operation data when they require. Please note, there is no Operation filter on the page. Can anyone please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Add a page item P1_SHOW_DELETED to the page. Set the page item value to default "N" (or set it to "N" with a computation before regions). Use "Select List" and give it values "Yes" and "No" (return values Y and N)
- Update your query to use the page item. Make sure you have P1_SHOW_DELETED in "Page Items to Submit" attribute of the interactive report.

```
SELECT <columns>
  FROM <tables> 
 WHERE <existing where clause> AND operation_deleted = :P1_SHOW_DELETED
```

At this point the delete rows will no be shown on page load - test and confirm.

- Add a dynamic action on P1_SHOW_DELETED on change with a true action of type "Refresh" and region = your interactive report.

--- UPDATE ---

For multiple values for the operation column and you want to exclude/included the value "deleted", then this is an option.

```
SELECT <columns>
  FROM <tables> 
 WHERE <existing where clause> AND 
       (('Y' = :P1_SHOW_DELETED AND operation = 'Deleted') OR (operation != 'Deleted'))
```

Comment: Thank you for quick reply @Koen. However,I had a doubt -  the column operation has 8 distinct values(Deleted, Repoened,Open, completed etc etc). How will the item P1_SHOW_DELETED will work for all the other operations.

Comment: There is no sample data in your question or no reference to that structure - it states "see the deleted operation data". If you want a more detailed answer then pls update your question with data structure, sample data and expected output. Edit the question, don't put that in comments pls.

Comment: Got your point, will keep in mind in future. Also, I tried the checkbox(instead of select list I opted for checkbox)  functionality and it worked for me. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @SQL_Learner check my update, I added the where clause for a case like yours